# How to determine listboxitem a button was pressed from?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, listbox

Basically I'm dynamically adding items to a listbox. Inside of each listbox item I have also added a button control that will perform a specific action on the item from which the button was clicked.

```
<DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title"/>
    <Button Click="MyBtn_Click"/>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Does anyone know how to determine which item the button was clicked from? I know each listbox item contains an index. I think if you could access the parent of the button you could then deterimine which button was clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the CommmandParameter of the button to hold a value -

```
<DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel>     
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/> 
    <Button Click="MyBtn_Click" CommandParameter={Binding Title}/>   
    </StackPanel> 
</DataTemplate> 

public void MyBtn_Click(object sender, args)
{
    string MyVal = (sender as Button).CommandParameter.ToString();
}
```

Convention is to use the Command event instead of the click event for this type of thing.